# Commands in skills created in caldera don't work on the victim machine, but they do work directly on the victim machine

Tags: mitre-attck

The environment is as follows, a victim machine (w11 with mimikatz installed) and an attacker machine (kali with caldera installed).

when you want to execute the code in cmd:
powershell.exe "IEX Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Users\User\Downloads\master-mimikatz\mimikatz.exe" -Verb RunAs"; lsadump::lsa /patch"
Works on w11 but does not work for the skill created in caldera.